# Everyone but three

Tags: riddle, knowledge

For the first time, a photo was taken with every person, living or dead, in frame. Everyone that is except for three. Who were those three?

Comment: If it were "everyone but one" instead, then I'd go for https://rarehistoricalphotos.com/michael-collins-picture-1969/

Comment: @Eagle I thought about doing that, but I thought 3 was a better hint and less likely to have alternate correct answers (everyone but the photographer might have other clever options).

Comment: This one... kinda made the rounds on the meme networks.... Sorry. :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> The three  astronauts in the space shuttle taking the photo: Frank Borman, James Lovell, and William Anders.
>
>  The photo is called *Earthrise* and was taken during the Apollo 8 mission in 1968.

Comment: I thought I might fool people with the later, more famous, group of three.  Great job, remembering these earlier pioneers!